# Using Awk to Find Files ending in .c

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, awk, ls

I am writing an awk script which looks like this inside:

```
BEGIN{print "Name\t  Size\t\t  Access"}
{if($10~/[1-9].[c]) printf "%-10s %-10s %-5s\n", $10, $6, $1}
```

This tries to find files ending in .c but instead it gives me files that have .c within the name. My output looks like this:

```
lab1.cpp 
Lab2.cpp 
prog1.c  
prog2.c 
prog3.c.txt
```

I have to use the awk command to find these files. How do I fix it this to get this:

```
prog1.c  
prog2.c
```

Comment: I assume that you want to learn about `awk`, because there are far more useful ways to search for specific files than that. Look at `find` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use end anchor in your regex and shorten your awk by removing `if` and conditional blocks:

```
BEGIN{print "Name\t  Size\t\t  Access"}
$10 ~ /[1-9]\.c$/ { printf "%-10s %-10s %-5s\n", $10, $6, $1}
```